# How to return from then of a Future in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a function which does some asynchronous operations and I want to return the status of the operation back to the caller. How can I achieve this?

```
Future<bool> setData() async {
    Firestore.instance.collection("test").document('$id').setData({
      'id': 'test'
    }).then((onValue) {
      print('Data set success');
      return true;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print('Data set Error!!!');
      return false;
    });
  }

//Calling
final status = await setData();
if(status){
  //do success
}
```

But this function complains that it doesn't end with a return statement. What is the logical mistake I'm making here?

Comment: Note that your `async` keyword isn't accomplishing anything here since you have no `await`. Consider rewriting this to use `await` and `try`/`catch` instead of `.then()` and `.catchError()`. https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-asyncawait-over-using-raw-futures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss a return in your `setData` function

```
  return Firestore.instance....
```